# Mysql, Check field value change?

Tags: mysql, sql

Mysql, Check field value change? if change the value then show different value

table: a

```
   id  size  name
   --------------
   1   500   abc
   2   200   bcd
   3   400   xyz
   4   500   bbb
   5   200   aaa


  select @s:=@s+1 as index, id, size, name from a,(SELECT @s:= 0) AS s order by size;
```

In this query data like.

```
   index id  size  name
   --------------------

   1     2   200   bcd
   2     5   200   aaa
   3     3   400   xyz
   4     1   500   abc
   5     4   500   bbb
```

I need to get index change when size is change.
I want to get this type of data. like.

```
   index id  size  name
   --------------------

   1     2   200   bcd
   1     5   200   aaa
   2     3   400   xyz
   3     1   500   abc
   3     4   500   bbb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT
  @s := @s + (@prev_size != a.size) `index`,
  id,
  @prev_size := a.size size,
  name
FROM a, (SELECT @s := 0, @prev_size := -1) s
ORDER BY a.size
```

Output:

```
| INDEX | ID | SIZE | NAME |
|-------|----|------|------|
|     1 |  2 |  200 |  bcd |
|     1 |  5 |  200 |  aaa |
|     2 |  3 |  400 |  xyz |
|     3 |  1 |  500 |  abc |
|     3 |  4 |  500 |  bbb |
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d314/1).

Comment: Hello, Mosty Mostacho.
some time index are start with 2, why?

Comment: For example last record in 'a' table, its size 200 then index are star with 2 other wise start with 1.
Whats's reason?

Comment: I've slightly modified the answer. Make sure `@prev_size` is initialised to a value that is not int the table. If this doesn't work then, please, create a fiddle displaying the issue.