# mysql detect field value change

Tags: mysql

I have found a very similar question with exact same title here: [Mysql, Check field value change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278729/mysql-check-field-value-change), but it is not exactly what I need.

DB: MySql, Table: tbl_geodata

I have query:

```
SELECT id,timestamp,ver_fw FROM tbl_geodata
WHERE imei LIKE '353227026533507'
```

Result is:

```
--Full data
+------+---------------------+--------+
| id   | timestamp           | ver_fw |
+------+---------------------+--------+
                 ...
                 ...
| 813  | 2014-09-10 11:24:01 | 2.5.0  |       
| 1457 | 2014-09-15 14:07:03 | 2.5.0  |
| 1458 | 2014-09-15 14:15:33 | 2.5.0  |
| 1467 | 2014-09-15 15:08:29 | 2.5.0  |
| 1468 | 2014-09-15 15:19:36 | 2.5.0  |
| 1469 | 2014-09-15 16:35:46 | 2.5.2  |
| 1470 | 2014-09-15 16:52:58 | 2.5.2  |
| 1471 | 2014-09-15 17:14:47 | 2.5.2  |
| 1472 | 2014-09-15 17:52:59 | 2.5.3  |
| 1473 | 2014-09-16 09:51:59 | 2.5.3  |
| 1474 | 2014-09-16 09:53:16 | 2.5.3  |
| 1506 | 2014-09-16 10:36:45 | 2.5.3  |
                  ...
                  ...
```

What I want is to check any changes in ver_fw and select only this rows:

```
--Correct results
+------+---------------------+--------+
| id   | timestamp           | ver_fw |
+------+---------------------+--------+
| 4    | 2014-07-08 18:02:22 | 2.4.19 | 
| 813  | 2014-09-10 11:24:01 | 2.5.0  | 
| 1469 | 2014-09-15 16:35:46 | 2.5.2  | 
| 1472 | 2014-09-15 17:52:59 | 2.5.3  | 
| 1543 | 2014-09-16 15:28:18 | 2.5.4  | 
| 1551 | 2014-09-17 11:37:12 | 2.4.19 |     
| 1555 | 2014-09-18 12:11:04 | 2.5.0  | 
| 1557 | 2014-09-18 13:59:22 | 2.5.4  | 
| 1563 | 2014-09-18 14:43:22 | 2.5.5  | 
| 1637 | 2014-09-23 15:42:07 | 2.5.6  | 
| 1660 | 2014-09-24 10:21:42 | 2.5.7  | 
| 1682 | 2014-09-25 14:51:20 | 2.5.8  | 
| 1692 | 2014-09-26 10:38:39 | 2.4.19 |     
| 5290 | 2015-04-08 20:11:38 | 2.4.81 |
+------+---------------------+--------+
```

I have tried to change my query like answered in the same question, but I've failed:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    TIMESTAMP,
    @prev_ver := ver_fw ver_fw
FROM tbl_geodata, (SELECT @prev_ver := -1)s
WHERE imei LIKE  '353227026533507' AND @prev_ver != tbl_geodata.ver_fw
```

Result:

```
--Incorrect results
+------+---------------------+--------+
| id   | TIMESTAMP           | ver_fw |
+------+---------------------+--------+
|    4 | 2014-07-08 18:02:22 | 2.4.19 |
|  813 | 2014-09-10 11:24:01 | 2.5.0  |
| 1551 | 2014-09-17 11:37:12 | 2.4.19 |
| 1555 | 2014-09-18 12:11:04 | 2.5.0  |
| 1692 | 2014-09-26 10:38:39 | 2.4.19 |
+------+---------------------+--------+
```

Unfortunately, I can not understand a reason. How can I get only rows with value that changes from previous?

P.S. sorry for my english.

Comment: Does the last query runs?

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use a trigger:  http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/

Comment: You have rows in the second result that do not appear in the first result. How is this supposed to make sense to anyone?

Comment: @holpducki, yes, it runs.

Comment: @Strawberry, I've used '.....' to show that is only part of result

Comment: Yes. It's almost useless to us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way to do it using variables:

```
SELECT id, `timestamp`, ver_fw
FROM (
  SELECT id, `timestamp`, ver_fw,
         IF ( @prev_ver <> ver_fw, 
             IF (@prev_ver := ver_fw, 1, 1),
             IF (@prev_ver := ver_fw, 0, 0)) AS IsDifferent
  FROM tbl_geodata
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prev_ver := '-1') AS var
  WHERE imei LIKE '353227026533507'
  ORDER BY `timestamp` ) t
WHERE IsDifferent = 1
ORDER BY `timestamp`
```

The first-level `IF` checks for inequality. The second level is used in order to assign `@prev_ver` its *next* value and to return `1` / `0`, depending on inequality / equality to previous value of `ver_fw`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/859fd/5)

Comment: It works perfectly from web interface, thank you very much! But from console I have an collation error `ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (cp866_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '<>'`

Comment: I've fixed this error using console by sending `SET collation_connection=latin1_swedish_ci;`

Comment: Too bad the variables cannot be seen by other sessions/users.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the previous value using variables is a bit more challenging than it should be.

Fortunately, if you have an index on `tbl_geodata(timestamp)` (or `id` if that defines the ordering), you can get good performance with a correlated subquery:

```
select gd.*,
       (select gd2.ver_fw
        from tbl_geodata gd2
        where gd2.timestamp < gd.timestamp <-- id might also be used here
        order by gd2.timestamp desc
        limit 1
       ) as prev_ver_fw
from tbl_geodata gd
having prev_ver_fw is null or prev_ver_fw <> ver_fw;
```

Note that this uses a MySQL extension by using a `having` clause with no `group by`.  This saves an extra layer of subquery'ing for the final condition.

Comment: _id_ is auto increment primary key. But my server doesn't answer to your query at all. Look like endless loop or something. Neither web interface nor console doesn't answer after I've tried to run this query.

Comment: @Exerion . . . You can try changing the `timestamp` in the subquery to `id` (including in the `order by`).  If `id` is a primary key, it should be pretty fast.

Comment: I apologize, but it's still not working. I replaced the timestamp to id in the inner query, but the server still does not respond. Giorgos Betsos's answer works perfectly.

Comment: @Exerion . . . Interesting.  I would expect this to have good performance with the appropriate index.  I wonder why it is not working well for you.

Comment: I accidentally left the console launched, after then I saw your query is done in 18 minutes 57 seconds and returned almost all of the rows from the database (over two thousand)